# Zooming out animation Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do some animation for a UIImageView (only zooming out)

1- I set the frame to be bigger than the screen to make it zoomed in like so :

```
private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width + 300, height: view.frame.height + 300)
    image.center = view.center
    image.image = UIImage(named: "1111")
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return image
}()
```

and I want to make the frame go back to the screen size like so :

```
func firstAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 15, animations: {

        // HERE 
        self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    }) { (finished) in
        self.secondAnimation()
    }
}
```

I didn't work with me unfortunately.

Here the full class code :
[github](https://gist.github.com/cs4alhaider/5399bdcdb16f3af9e388395ffbd735d3)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Swift 4+

Use `CGAffineTransform.identity` to resize your image to it's first `identity`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        
       // HERE
       self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2) // Scale your image

 }) { (finished) in
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
       
      self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity // undo in 1 seconds

   })
}
```

Comment: I need It only to be zoomed out

Comment: Check the code on https://gist.github.com/cs4alhaider/5399bdcdb16f3af9e388395ffbd735d3

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIView {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
          self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)
      }) { (finished) in
          UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
          self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
      })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for zoom in:

```c
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    imgv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
}];
```

Code for zoom out:

```c
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    imgv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1,0.1);           
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    imgv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.0,.0);    
}];
```

Here `imvv` is my `UIImageview` object. You can replace it with your view object. In `zoom out` code we hide the view by `scaling` it to `0`.